# Is it possible to set an Android Notification or a later date and time that will fire when the app is not running?

Tags: java, android, notifications

From what I have read it seems that code like this would require the app to be running in a thread until the notification fires. I need the notification to fire at a later date and time so the user sees the notification just like any other notification and then clicks it and it opens of an activity, passing in some data so the app knows what to do.

How can I make this notification fire days later without the app running the whole time?

Do I use wait to accomplish this?

```
long millis = 60000;
myNotification.wait(millis);
```

Here is my code which fires immediately

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity())
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.star)
.setContentTitle("How was " + me.getString("EventTitle") + "?")
.setContentText("Click here to leave your review");

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SetupActivity.class);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
PendingIntent.getActivity(
getActivity(),
0,
resultIntent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    int mNotificationId = me.getInt("EventID");
    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
            (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: No, you'd normally use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: Okay, so AlarmManager will also produce that same style of notification, like a push notification that you see when you pull down the top of the screen on android phones?

Comment: `AlarmManager` schedules a `PendingIntent` execution. Usually you'd make that `PendingIntent` target a `BroadcastReceiver` that creates your notification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As A--C wrote, use `AlarmManager` to schedule a `PendingIntent` to be invoked at your desired time. You will probably use an `RTC_WAKEUP` alarm, meaning "the time is based on `System.currentTimeMillis()`, like `Calendar` uses" and "let's wake up the device out of sleep mode". Use a broadcast `PendingIntent`, and your `Notification` code can go into the `onReceive()` method, if you do not need to do any disk or network I/O to get the information to use for the `Notification` itself.

Note that in Android 4.4 the rules for `AlarmManager` changed a bit. You will want to use `setExact()` on Android 4.4+ and `set()` on earlier Android versions.

Comment: Can you schedule more than one Notification this way? What happens if the device is rebooted?

Comment: @PaulG: "Can you schedule more than one Notification this way?" -- sure. "What happens if the device is rebooted?" -- `AlarmManager` is wiped out, and you will need to re-establish your alarms.