# Android equivalent of iOS' UILocalNotification

Tags: android, ios

I'm looking for the Android equivalent of `UILocalNotification` (a simple way to schedule a local notification in iOS).

Ideally I would create a local notification and assign it a date and time, and have it fire at that date and time.

In iOS, I create a `UILocalNotification` and set it's `fireDate`, and the operating system takes care of firing it at the date and time provided. I don't have to have any background processes running, no timers.

Is there anything like this in Android?

**EDIT: I want to be able to "schedule" a notification for a later date. Not one to be fired right away. Even when my app is off or sleeping I would like this to happen. I have read the official documentation on Notifications and have found NOTHING useful, I'm hoping someone who has been through this already can provide an alternative to AlarmManager**

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Where in that document does it say I can schedule a notification for a specific date and time and have the OS handle it like UILocalNotificaton does? Can't find it. That is why I'm asking this question, to have someone who has possibly achieved what I am asking and kindly provide an answer. Not Google and send me the first link that comes up and blame the asker for being lazy.

Comment: @XaverKapeller The answer to my question is the Android documentation page for `Notification`? Sorry, I've read it and it's not answering my question.  Where can I specify a date and time in the `NotificationCompat.Builder`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, I have discovered that the simplicity and convenience of `UILocalNotification` is not there in `Android Notifications`. So no, I cannot achieve what I'm trying to achieve through the `NotificationManager` object alone.

However, I can use `AlarmManager` for a similar effect, as is mentioned in the following StackOverflow post:

[Is it possible to set an Android Notification or a later date and time that will fire when the app is not running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420350/is-it-possible-to-set-an-android-notification-or-a-later-date-and-time-that-will)